What is the best way to play audio resources in a car app?
I am currently developing an app that needs to receive notifications with important information. One of these notifications refers to an audio resource, which I play using a MediaPlayer.
When testing on real vehicles, I noticed that the audio only plays if the app is in the foreground, but it plays from my phone rather than through the car's system.
Is there a way to keep the current behavior while playing the audio through the car using the Messaging category?
Alternatively, if I switch to the Media category, will I still be able to use notifications?
If you believe another category might be a better fit for my app and help achieve the functionality I need, I would appreciate your advice.
